# Suma en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL Server 2014

```
Codigo nchar(10)
1 float
2 float
3 float
4 float
5 float
6 float
7 float
8 float
9 float
10  float
```

Ahora de este resultado necesito sumar las columnas 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:

```
Codigo  1    2   3   4    5     6   7    8     9    10
301     NULL 8.9 78  NULL 56.98 98  NULL 10.87 23.4  987.01
```

```
select V.Codigo, sum(V.Cantidad) AS Cantidad
from(select Codigo, ([1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10])as Cantidad 
from ProyeccionZ)V
GROUP BY V.Codigo
```

Pero me da como resultado NULL y no entiendo que hago mal

```
Codigo Cantidad
301    NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que ***null*** + número = ***null***. Entonces necesitas utilizar una función como **[isnull](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** para reemplazar el null por 0.

Así:

```
create table prueba
(
codigo varchar(10),
[1] float null,
[2] float null
)
```

Hacemos unos insert de prueba:

```
insert into prueba values ('01',1,null)
insert into prueba values ('02',2,3)
```

Si ejecutamos:

```
select codigo, [1]+[2] as suma
from prueba
```

Obtenemos:

```
codigo,suma
'02',5.0
'01',null
```

Pero si probamos con:

```
select codigo, isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)
from prueba
```

Obtenemos el resultado correcto:

```
codigo,suma
'01',1.0
'02',5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Creeria que con un group by consigues tu resultado ademas de validar que si un dato es null lo convierta a cero para poder sumar:

```
select V.Codigo, sum(IsNull([1], 0) +IsNull([2], 0)IsNull([3], 0)IsNull([4], 0)IsNull([5], 0)IsNull([6], 0)IsNull([7], 0)IsNull([8], 0)IsNull([9], 0)IsNull([10], 0))as Cantidad 
from ProyeccionZ)V
 GROUP BY V.Codigo
```

Comment: Da de resultado NULL :C

Comment: he editado la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Existe un método alternativo que consiste en convertir las columnas en filas y después usar una función de agregación como SUM().

En este caso, utilizo `APPLY` con la clausula `VALUES` para formar las filas, pero se podría usar `UNPIVOT`.

```
SELECT p.codigo, SUM(x.Cantidades) AS Cantidad
FROM ProyeccionZ p
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(p.[1]),(p.[2]),(p.[3]),(p.[4]),(p.[5]),(p.[6]),(p.[7]),(p.[8]),(p.[9]),(p.[10]))x(Cantidades)
GROUP BY codigo;
```

Comment: da este error 'x' tiene más columnas de las especificadas en la lista de columnas.

Comment: Mi código no genera ese error. El problema puede presentarse si estás usando * en un INSERT en vez de una lista de columnas. O si especificaste las columnas pero no concuerdan entre el INSERT y el SELECT.